# Slim working on local dev machine but not remote server

Tags: php, slim

I'm playing around with Slim, and it works great on my local machine running MAMP. The root URL shows "home" and /features shows "features". On my Linode machine, however, only the root works ("home"). When I go to /features I get a 404.

```
<?php

//Slim Framework
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

//Instantiate, register URIs
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'debug' => true
));

$app->get('/', 'getHome');
$app->get('/features', 'getFeatures');

$app->run();

function getHome() {
    echo "home";
};


function getFeatures() {
    echo "features";
};

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have mod rewrite turned on in my .htaccess file. Uploading the following .htaccess fixed my problem:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```